# Dedupe a SQLite table

Tags: sqlite, duplicates

Want to use select distict * from table_a to create entries in table_b

used .schema to find creation properties of table_a
created table_b to match

Tried:
INSERT INTO table_b values(select distinct * from table_a) ;

SQL error: near "select": syntax error

Can someone help me with the obvious point I missing?

Answer (score 5):

You need to do:

```
insert into table_b select distinct * from table_a;
```

No need for `values` keyword.

Answer (score 1):

You should omit `VALUES` if your insertions are going to come from a subquery. See the [syntax of the `INSERT` statement](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html).